# Use IPSec tunneling in SoftEtherVPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, l2tp

I'm trying to connect from my iOS app to a SoftEtherVPN server. For that I'm using IPSec in tunneling mode. As far as I can see in SoftEtherVPN only L2TP over IPSEc is supported.

Is this correct, or do you know of any way of using pure IPSec without L2TP ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it turned out, there's no IPSec in tunneling mode support in SoftEtherVPN, Only L2TP or EtherIP over IPSec.

So as of now September 2016 there's no way to connect programmatically from an iphone to SoftEtherVPN.

I'm studying SoftEtherVPN code as well as some RFCs related to IPSec and IKEv1 with the hope of implementing this feature myself.

Ping me if you as well are interested in this feature